# How to change php variables from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a condition in my blade file @if($url['applied'] == true) and i want to change this condition on basis of my ajax call value.. I have tried

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "",
          headers: '',
          url: '', 
          data: '',
          success: function(data) {
            <?php $url['applied'] = false ?>;
          }
      });
```

Comment: No ! You should only get changed php variable from server by ajax.....

Comment: I think you might want to read up on how the frontend (your JavaScript) talks to the backend (your Laravel app), because it's: 1) browser asks for webpage including JavaScript 2) Laravel gives that to the browser 3) You can execute Javascript to ask for more data, but what was sent in step 1 stays the same, you can only modify it.

Comment: @Thomas i want to modify my variable but it is not reflecting in my blade file

Comment: @JainamShah Yes I know and I try to explain as to why it does not work. But if you just want to change that var, make it persistent by setting it in a session var. Those will persist between page loads. This will however not reload the page

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstanding/misconception here.

The ajax call can be made **after** the PHP (Laravel) renders the HTML file and load it into your browser. Then the ajax call is done in your browser, not in the server. So you cannot asign a PHP variable from client/browser side.

What you can do is that you can create a JavaScript variable inside blade file (which is not recommended btw (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/1331040)):

```
var urlApplied = {{$url['applied']}};
```

Then hide/show the content based on ajax response:

```
jQuery.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(data) {
        urlApplied = data.response; // or whatever the property you have instead of 'response'
      }
  });
```

Since you haven't provided the content you want to hide/show, I cannot give more specific hide/show logic but hope this gives you a clue.

But I strongly suggest you to reconsider the logic by decoupling the browser and client side flows (you can read the answers in the link I shared above).